# Full-Text Search Through My Bookmarks?

Tags: browser, search, bookmarks, search-engines

I would like to be able to search through pages which I have bookmarked. Like a Google search but limited to my bookmarks.

Firefox allows you to search through your bookmarks but only the URL, Title and Description are saved.

Is this functionality available in any browser or external tool?

Answer (score 0):

Safari provides built-in full-text search of history since version 5, and for Firefox i found this extension on Google:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/infoaxe-web-history-search-and/

(The page won't load for me right now, so i'm sorry if that's not what i thought it was)

I have not heard of any browser or extension that provides full-text search of bookmarks independent of their presence in history, but the browser would obviously have to download each bookmarked page before providing you that functionality anyway, so it might be an acceptable work-around.

Comment: This addon doesn't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://fetching.io -- It saves the full text of every webpage you visit and let's you search on everything later. There is even a native version that runs on your computer so your information is completely private.

Comment: It may be nice to disclose your involvement with the project, even more so if the project requires a fee.